# Dynamic Search without dynamic SQL

Tags: sql

A user can search for a customer by Firstname, LastName and optionally entering a City.

Is it possible to write a SQL that matches on CITY only if the user entered one w/o using dynamic SQL?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchCustomer]
@FirstName varchar(30) --REQUIRED
@LastName varchar(30)--REQUIRED
@City varchar(30)  --OPTIONAL
AS
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE
C.FirstName = @FirstName AND
C.LastName = @LastName AND
C.City = IsNull(@City, C.City) --This won't Work if CITY is optional in the database
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
(@City is null OR C.City = @City)
```

Comment: That won't work because, in the situation where they specified a City, the query will return Customer records with a NULL city.

Comment: @Velika: It shouldn't, because `null = null` is not true.  Try it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
COALESCE(C.City,"") = COALESCE(@City,C.City,"")
```

More info about this function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: +1. Same solution as I had in mind *(with only a much faster brain to get there)*. *(own answer deleted)*

Comment: For the 2nd answer, the ISNULL function only takes 2 args. Don't understand the first YET

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchCustomer]
@FirstName varchar(30) --REQUIRED
@LastName varchar(30)--REQUIRED
@City varchar(30)  --OPTIONAL
AS

IF @City is NULL
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE
C.FirstName = @FirstName AND
C.LastName = @LastName
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE
C.FirstName = @FirstName AND
C.LastName = @LastName AND
C.City = @City
END
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought iof that, but if we have 2 or more fields that can be NULL, the permutations can get ou of hand